# VSCode and Live Server - change port

Tags: liveserver

Trying to configure Live Server to properly launch and connect to web pages on my local machine in VSCode .However, I seem unable to set the port I want to run live server on. When I accept the default port (chosen by the extension itself) I get ERR_UNSAFE_PORT from both Chrom and Firefox.

I have tried changing the settings, but its seems to be ignoring anything I put in there. Can someone please advise ?

Here is a screenshot of where I am trying to set the port..

[image: Live Server Settings]

Thanks..

P.S It does not matter what value I use for the port (2000 here just as an example.) Whatever you put in is ignored. tried various,, 8080 etc..

Answer (score -1):

`https://github.com/ritwickdey/vscode-live-server/issues/2611`
May local config overrides the global config？

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).